# GDrive Disable Copying and downloading

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

How I can manage the sharing-feature: "Disable Copying and downloading" without the advanced Drive Service?

Currently I solve it about:

```js
function mySolveAboutAdvancedService(id) {
  var file = Drive.Files.get(id);
  file.labels.restricted = true;
  Drive.Files.update(file, id);
}
```

Why I can change all settings but not this one without the advanced Drive Service?

Thanks

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

- You want to achieve the following script without using Advanced Google services.

  ```
  var file = Drive.Files.get(id);
  file.labels.restricted = true;
  Drive.Files.update(file, id);
  ```
- You want to know the reason that "Disable Copying and downloading" cannot be achieved without using above script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Issue and workaround:

Drive API of Advanced Google services uses Drive API v2. In this case, `labels.restricted` is for Drive API v2, and also, the official document says as follows.

> `labels.restricted`: Warning: This item is deprecated. Deprecated - use `copyRequiresWriterPermission` instead.

By this, when `{labels: {restricted: true}}` is used for Drive API v3, it cannot be used while no error occurs. But, when Drive API v2 is used with UrlFetchApp, `{labels: {restricted: true}}` can be still used. By this, your script using Drive API of Advanced Google service works.

In order to achieve your script without using Advanced Google services, please directly request to the endpoint of Drive API v3 (in this case, v3 is used.) with the request body of `{copyRequiresWriterPermission: true}` using UrlFetchApp. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
function mySolveAboutAdvancedService() {
  var id = "###";  // Please set the file ID.

  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + id;
  var params = {
    method: "patch",
    contentType: "application/json",
    payload: JSON.stringify({copyRequiresWriterPermission: true}),
    headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}
  };
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  Logger.log(res.getContentText())
}
```

#### Note:

- If you want to use Drive API v2 with UrlFetchApp, how about the following script? At Drive API v2, both `{labels: {restricted: true}}` and `{copyRequiresWriterPermission: true}` can be used.

  ```
  function mySolveAboutAdvancedService() {
    var id = "###";  // Please set the file ID.

    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/" + id;
    var params = {
      method: "put",
      contentType: "application/json",
      payload: JSON.stringify({copyRequiresWriterPermission: true}),  // or payload: JSON.stringify({labels: {restricted: true}})
      headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}
    };
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
    Logger.log(res.getContentText())
  }
  ```

#### References:

- [Files of Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files)
- [Files of Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files)
- [Files: update of Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.